# AS3 Dynamic variable naming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, dynamic

Is dynamic variable naming like this possible in ActionScript 3?

```
for (var xz=0;xz<10;xz++){
    var this['name' + xz]:Number = xz;
}
```

Comment: no it's not, use array or any other object able to store other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array for this kind of list of variables.
While you can create properties dynamically, you usually want to avoid it. Especially in your case, where the actual identifier of each variable is not a `String`, but a number. So why not use something that does exactly that: identify its elements by a number? And that's exactly what an array does.

code example:

```
var xzs:Array = [];
for (var xz:uint = 0; xz < 10; xz++){
    xzs.push(xz);
}
```

Comment: Because, for example, you cannot perform an easy look-up later on. If you have 20k items and you want to get particular one, it's much easier to query `this['xz' + 3176]` (having in mind that order might not be guaranteed).

Comment: @AndreyPopov I disagree. `xzs[3176]` should work just fine and is not any harder to do. Given that the existence of a dynamic property cannot be checked at compile time, I highly suggest working with an array. This question is not about 20k elements, but 10.

Comment: If we are talking about array, using `xzs[3176]` would make array of length `3177` (because of 0), with single item in it. If we are talking about Objects - any kind of Number as key is really **bad** - they are all converted to Strings anyway.

Comment: @AndreyPopov No, this is what only you are talking about. This question (and my answer) is not about setting a single arbitrary large element of an array. This thread is about a for loop that creates elements, which runs continuously and starts with 0. This is why there is no such problem `because of 0`. The elements of the array start at 0 just the same as the dynamic properties of an object.  I never suggested to set elements this way either. Your comments appear to be rather unrelated to my answer, given in the context of the question.

Comment: The question is **Is dynamic variable naming like this possible**, right? And your answer starts with "You should use an array for this kind of list of variables".. so let's think about a second what's relevant and what's not :)

Comment: I just read your comment again. "The elements of the array start at 0 just the same as the dynamic properties of an object." - this freaks me out, and I just realized there's no point arguing, as long as you say dynamic properties of an object "start at 0"...

Comment: @AndreyPopov solving Y of an XY problem is something I consider to be less relevant than solving X, indeed. The properties and the indices of the array start at 0. `xzs[0]`will be the first array element added and `this["xy" + 0]` will be the first property added. If this freaks you out, I'm sorry, but it's the way it is. It appears to me that you are trying to be very nitpicky about something that's not part of my answer. I'm not sure what you are trying to prove here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sure is - AS3 comes from ECMA script, so this is setting a property to an object (in this case it's `this`). So you can dynamically set properties. But you are a little bit wrong about how to do it - there is no need to use `var`, because you don't declare it, you **set** it. It's like using:

```
this.propertyName = 'value';
```

From now on, `this` will have `propertyName` equal to `'value`'. Therefore you should just use:

```
this['name' + xz] = xz;
```

That's all!

Edit: as BotMaster mentioned - if you are using classes and you want to dynamically add properties, the class must be set as dynamic. Most of the commonly used ones are already dynamic (as Aaron mentioned :)).
I didn't go into much details as I think you simply need to do this on your timeline. If not - please specify this in your question so that you can get more accurate answer than this one. The same goes if your new property needs to be typed (can't think of any point wanting this) - you should see BotMaster's answer :)

Comment: that's not true, only dynamic class can do that.

Comment: If `this` is a `MovieClip` (which it is if this is a timeline script) then it is dynamic class already.

Comment: You're both correct, I just thought the user wants something much more basic than BotMaster's idea.. :)

Comment: I just followed the PO precise question about using "var" and a type (:Number), that's the part that cannot be done. Untyped sure there's plenty of ways, typed besides Vector I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no, you can't declare at runtime typed properties.

Long answer is: kinda.

If you want to create new typed properties you'll have to store them in a Vector<>.

Anything else would let you do it but untyped, dynamic class, store in object, store in array, etc ...